# Different alias for ROLLUP function

Tags: sql

Is there any way to change the name of `ROLLUP` function only for last row?

I want to change only the name of highlighted text from picture. That means that the last total to be written as 'Total general' instead of 'Total Judet'.

[image: This is the result that I get]

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN (GROUPING(l.DenLoc) = 1) THEN 'Total Judet'
        When l.DenLoc is null then 'Total General' 
        Else l.DenLOc End  AS Localitate,
  l.Jud,
  COUNT(case when EXTRACT (month FROM DataContr)=01 AND EXTRACT (year FROM DataContr) =2016 then 1  end) AS Ianuarie,
  COUNT(case when EXTRACT (month FROM DataContr)=02 AND EXTRACT (year FROM DataContr) =2016 then 1 end) AS Februarie,
  COUNT(case when EXTRACT (month FROM DataContr)=03 AND EXTRACT (year FROM DataContr) =2016 then 1 end) AS Martie,
  COUNT(case when EXTRACT (month FROM DataContr)<4 AND EXTRACT (year FROM DataContr) =2016 then 1 end) AS Total_Trim_I
FROM Contraventii c
     INNER JOIN Localitati l ON c.IdLocContr=l.IdLoc
GROUP BY ROLLUP ( l.Jud, l.DenLoc)
ORDER BY l.Jud;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN GROUPING(l.DenLoc) = 1 AND GROUPING(l.Jud) = 1
             THEN 'Your Name Here'
             WHEN GROUPING(l.DenLoc) = 1 THEN 'Total Judet'
             WHEN l.DenLoc is null then 'Total General' 
             ELSE l.DenLOc 
        END) AS Localitate,
```